# VueJS - Remove html inside slot if it's not my component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuejs-slots

I have component-a and component-b, the default slot of component-a must render only component-b and other elements with different tags must be removed

```html
<component-a> 
    
    <component-b></component-b> // render
    <component-b></component-b> // render
    
    <div></div> // remove
    <input /> //remove
    
</component-a>
```

What should I do?!

Comment: Slots are meant to be dynamic.  If it shouldn't be dynamic, don't use a slot.  Just replace it with component-b

Comment: You need to filter them out by vnode.type in parent's render function

Comment: If there's a condition of using one of each so you can go with `v-if` and `v-else`, as slots are dynamic and if you want to use it as static purpose so it better not to use or make a child component and have condition.